# Python ThreadPoolExecutor count of futures missing to complete

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading, concurrent.futures

I am using a `TreadPoolExecutor` to run asynchronous tasks. I wanted to know if there is a way to list the futures that need to be completed without having to manually keep track of them. The Python documentation is somewhat sparse on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

Going through the [code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py) of the concurrent futures, there are two elements that can be useful:

`_threads_queues`[1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/713ba03276c4ddc33c9debc51b03164ea18eead6/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L30) holds a `WeakKeyDictionary` with the information of all the queues, useful if there are different executors defined.

Regarding the executor itself, the queue is held as `_work_queue`[2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/713ba03276c4ddc33c9debc51b03164ea18eead6/Lib/concurrent/futures/thread.py#L187). So, to have an idea of the amount of tasks that are waiting to run on a specific executor, you can do:

```py
executor._work_queue.qsize()
```

Just remember the [limitations](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/queue.html#queue.Queue.qsize) of qsize.